# Update my dataframe from a dictionary of list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, data-science

I have a dataframe with a certain ID and I also have a list dictionary. From the ID of the dataframe I need to update that ID if it exists in the dictionary but in the dictionary it is updated by two IDs, here are the examples:
Dataframe

| ID | Name | Last Name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Peter | Smith |
| 2 | John | Allen |
| 7 | Rene | Watson |
| 8 | Dilan | Foster |

Dictionary

`Dict = {1: [3, 4], 2: [5, 6], 7: [11], 8:[8]}`

Expect Output:

| ID | Name | Last Name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | Peter | Smith |
| 4 | Peter | Smith |
| 5 | John | Allen |
| 6 | John | Allen |
| 11 | Rene | Watson |
| 8 | Dilan | Foster |

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let us try `map` and `explode`

```
df.assign(ID=df['ID'].map(dct)).explode('ID', ignore_index=True)
```

---

```
  ID   Name Last Name
0  3  Peter     Smith
1  4  Peter     Smith
2  5   John     Allen
3  6   John     Allen
```

Comment: Thanks! But in the same table I have values that don't need to update, this works?

Comment: In that case we can use `df.assign(ID=df['ID'].map(dct).fillna(df['ID'])).explode('ID', ignore_index=True)`